# Middle + Center Alignment on Plotly

Tags: python, plotly

Are we able to do center + middle align text in Tables? In the documentation, I’ve only managed to find the option to horizontally center text, and couldn't find any post with this topic.

What I'm expecting is (I edited the picture so it will be center + middle aligned:

[image: What i expected]

What i got:

[image: What i got instead]

And if you're wondering what's my code, this is:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

layout = dict(
    paper_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)',
    plot_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)'
)

header = ['LVL', 'ATK', 'Elemental Mastery']
cells = [
         ['1', '10', '20', '30', '40', '50', '60', '70', '80', '90'],
         ['42', '77', '135', '170', '231', '292', '353', '414', '475', '510'],
         ['36', '49', '64', '78', '93', '107', '122', '136', '151', '165']
]

fig = go.Figure(layout=layout, data=[go.Table(
    header=dict(
        values=header,
        line_color='#3498DB',
        fill_color='rgba(0,0,0,0)',
        align='center',
        line=dict(width=2.5),
        font=dict(color='#3498DB', size=11.5)
    ),
    cells=dict(
        values=cells,
        line_color='#3498DB',
        fill_color='rgba(0,0,0,0)',
        align='center',
        height=30,
        line=dict(width=2.5),
        font=dict(color='#3498DB', size=13.5))
),
])
fig.update_layout(
    width=340, height=410 if len(header[-1:][0].split(' ')[0]) > 5 else 390,
    margin=dict(l=30, r=30, b=30, t=30)
)
fig.show()
```

Comment: Vertical centering of text is not a feature, so I think the limit is that it can be lowered just a bit by adding a line break tag. `values=[[f'<br>{header[0]}'], [f'<br>{header[1]}'], [f'{header[2].split(" ")[0]}<br>{header[2].split(" ")[1]}']]`